# Extract column names from a list of index number

Tags: python

I've got the following code from a video tutorial:

**Calling Program**

```
   X_train, X_test = remove_q_qc_dpl_feat(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
   sel = SelectPercentile(mutual_info_classif, percentile=10).fit(X_train, y_train)
   sel.fit(X_train, y_train)

   features = X_train.columns[sel.get_support()]
```

*PROBLEM:*
**features** returns a list of column index indexes like **[0, 6 23]**. What I need are the column names.

Here is the **FUNCTION** that is being called:

```
  def remove_q_qc_dpl_feat(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):

    # Remove constant and quasi constant
    constant_filter = VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.01)
    constant_filter.fit(X_train)
    X_train_filter = constant_filter.transform(X_train)
    X_test_filter = constant_filter.transform(X_test)

    #Remove duplicate
    X_train_T = X_train_filter.T
    X_test_T = X_test_filter.T

    X_train_T = pd.DataFrame(X_train_T)
    X_test_T = pd.DataFrame(X_test_T)  

    duplicated_features = X_train_T.duplicated()

    features_to_keep = [not index for index in duplicated_features]

    X_train_unique = X_train_T[features_to_keep].T
    X_test_unique = X_test_T[features_to_keep].T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the columns this way:

```
df.iloc[:,[0, 6, 23]].columns
```

---

Explaination:

`.iloc[]` gives you a slice of the dataframe

```
.iloc[0,1] would mean row 0 in coumn 1
```

`:` means all rows

so we are getting a slice of all rows for columns: [0, 6, 23]

.columns, gives you a list of names of the columns of the dataframe, or in this case the slice of the dataframe.

***EDIT SHOWS MY IMPLEMENTATION OF YOUR SUGGESTION***

```
   selected_columns = sel.getsupport()

   features = X_train.iloc[:,[selected_columns]].columns
```

the last line throws an error: *ndexError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 27.*

***You need to do it like this:***

```
selected_columns = X_train.columns[sel.get_support()]
X_train.iloc[:,selected_columns].columns
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your ideas. But using your suggestion I got this error: IndexError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 27.

Comment: X_train.iloc[:,X_train.columns[sel.get_support()]].columns you did it like this? If you did this already please print(X_train.columns) and let us know what is printed. Because maybe your columns names are  [0, 6, 23]. So name == index

Comment: Yes, columns looks like [0, 6, 23]. additional information: After constant_filter = VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.01) and X_train_filter = constant_filter.transform(X_train) transforms the data into numpy. the columns was also converted to numeric and columns becoms rows